# What happens when you change a reference inside a method? (7)

Tags: java

What happens when you change a reference inside a method?

```
public void reverseX(int[] nums) {
    int[] nums2 = new int[nums.length] ;
    for( int i=0 ; i < nums.length ; i++ )
        nums2[i] = nums[nums.length-(i+1)] ;
    nums = nums2 ;
};
```

This compiles fine.

Code is from here, and shown as an example of what not to do.

http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~cconway/teaching/cs1007/notes/arrays.pdf

Comment: It's not really hard to try and see right ? since the pointer to the array is passed by value - nothing will happen!

Comment: references are dynamic aliases. You make another array and make two pointers to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Objects, reference types are suppose to be immutable.

Not all of them. Some, but not all. For example, `String` is immutable, but `StringBuilder` isn't. All arrays are mutable.

> What happens here when nums is set to nums2.

The `nums` variable is given a new value, which is equal to the existing value of `nums2`.

That doesn't change the state of the *objects* that those variables refer to at all. It just changes the variable value itself.

Imagine the variables are pieces of paper. The integer array is like a house, and the values of the variables are like addresses written on the pieces of paper. This line:

```
nums = nums2 ;
```

... is just like copying what's written on one piece of paper onto another. That doesn't change the contents of the house that the address happens to refer to, right?

Now `nums` is just a local variable - because it's a parameter. That doesn't change anything in the *calling* code at all, because arguments are always passed by value in Java. So you're setting a local variable value just before the end of the method, and that's all. It will have no meaningful effect.

If none of this helps you, you'll need to ask a more specific question.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that I'm not saying that a reference is necessarily a memory address - the word "address" is just convenient in the analogy.

Comment: the professor made a strange comment about arrays references being immutable when passed in as a parameter.  This makes 0 sense, b.c. Java is always pass by Value and you are always working with a copy of what was passed in ... so I had to update my question.

Comment: @nativist.bill.cutting: Arrays themselves are always mutable. As for the references themselves - that doesn't make much sense as a concept, as you don't try to mutate a reference - you change the value of a variable, or data within an object.

Comment: You should join the nativists.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing happens.  Reference types are passed by-value, so `nums` is a local variable.  It doesn't affect anything outside the method.